# Adding process function in address field

Tags: 8, entities

I am customising address field so need to add *process* function in address field element.

If I am using following code, then its adding process function but then I am not able to call protected function which are defined in address class in address field module.

```
$info['address']['#process'][] = 'custom_feature_address_element_process';
```

If I am using following code, then its not working.

```
$info['address']['#process'][]  = array(0 => 'Drupal\customaddress\Element\CustomAddress', 1 => 'customprocessAddress');
```

Comment: Which class are you overriding?

Comment: I am overriding address class from address field module

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue using following code.

```
$info['address']['#process'][]  = 'Drupal\custom_feature\Element\CustomFeature::customprocessAddress';
```

Naming convention was also issue.